# Why is the display device not on google cloud windows server

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For some reason when i turn on my google cloud windows server there is no active GUI so i cant screen record anything.  This is the startup script:

[![Startup script][1]][1]

it works fine when i run the startup script with rdp using: C:\Program Files\Google\Compute Engine\metadata_scripts\run_startup_scripts.cmd I think its because closing rdp removes the gui but when i configured the server i turned on virtual display device isnt making a GUI.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjxcz.png

Comment: Can you provide more information like have you executed this startup-script before and was it working fine? Also Is **server.exe** file present in destination path.?

Comment: yes it works fine when i run the startup script with rdp using: C:\Program Files\Google\Compute Engine\metadata_scripts\run_startup_scripts.cmd

Answer (score 0):

It is like the remote desktop minimization is causing it. When tests are executed on a remote machine using Remote Desktop Connection and the RDC window remains minimised, native events (including taking screenshots) fail to work.

To fix this, one needs to add registry keys on the client machine from which the Remote Desktop Connection is made.

1. Launch Run and write 'regedit' to open Windows Registry on your machine
2. Find the registry key:

   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
3. Note: If any of the above keys is not present in your system, then just skip that key and proceed further.
4. Create a DWORD value with the name RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized and set its value to 2 in all the above registry keys.
5. Run the tests.

Now native events should work well with a minimised Remote Desktop Connection.

**Note : Registry keys are to be modified only on the client machine and not on the remote machine. Be cautious while changing these registry entries.**

Refer to the [links](https://resources.sahipro.com/docs/faq/remote-desktop-connection.html) for more information on [rdp](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/remote-desktop-connection-with-a-blank-screen/3f5f6e2c-3e10-4998-a6d6-6069fb54ed43).